# Python Dataframe - Use column names as index, and sum of columns as values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the column names are dates, and values are number of cases. However, there are 300+ daily columns. How do I create a series where the index is the column names (dates), and values are the sum of number of days for each column?

Input:

```
      Country     1/1/2020   1/2/2020  ...  12/31/2020
  0   Afganistan  50         100       ...  500
  1   Albania     20         50        ...  50
  ...
  99  Zimbabwe   6          10         ...  5
```

Desired output (pd.Series):

```
1/1/2020    76
1/2/2020    160
...
12/31/2020  555
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `set_index` to "Country" and `sum`:

```
out = df.set_index('Country').sum()
```

or drop "Country" and `sum`:

```
out = df.drop(columns='Country').sum()
```

Output:

```
1/1/2020       76
1/2/2020      160
12/31/2020    555
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) with `numeric_only=True` parameter:

```
s = df.sum(numeric_only=True)
print (s)
1/1/2020       76
1/2/2020      160
12/31/2020    555
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Transposing and summing should do the trick:

```
df.T.sum()
```

Where `df` is your `DataFrame`